# Deploy R statistical models in WSO2?

Tags: r, wso2

A newbie question on [WSO2](http://wso2.com/) and 'R'....

I have a customer where they are looking to build some statistical models using 'R'.  These models are mostly associated with customer scoring, i.e. sucking in a table of customer data with behavioural attributes as columns, and spitting out a 'score' for each customer.

Two questions on this:

- Can 'R' models by deployed like rules in a service model?
- Could you deploy R models into a WSO2 middleware, and if so, how and where?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Note: I'm not familiar with wso2 but I'm with R.

The answer to your question very much depends on what type of models you would like to deploy. The easiest ones are models such as linear/logistic regression followed by decision trees.

The reason they are easy is because for linear & logistic regression you get a nice formula you can plug-in to any programming interface. An example prediction formula might be like the following:

```
customer_predicted_life_time_value = 
17.25+2.365*num_of_products_held-16.12*time_at_address+25.36*monthly_income.
```

Similarly, decision trees can be easily exported as a bunch of `if-then-else` rules (there at least a couple of packages in R which will translate the R decision tree model into rules).

You could technically be able to deploy `randomForest` too in the form of rules but that will be cumbersome if you want to implenent using rules.